# Lenova Thinkpad Edge E430 Battery suddenly decrease from 50% to 7%

Tags: battery-life

I have using Lenova Thinkpad Edge E430. and i have installed windows 7 and Ubuntu. but i never used Ubuntu.

The battery life used to be 3 hour, but now a days it lasts only 30 minutes.  When battery in 50%, suddenly it drops to 7%..

Comment: did this issue happen after you installed Ubuntu

Comment: Ubuntu & W7 installed already, but the problem coming now a days

Comment: buy a new battery?

Comment: NO no. Its old one

Comment: I don't understand. The issue is likely the battery is old. See if you can buy a replacement battery

Comment: Replacement period is one year. but i have crossed more than one year. There is any other possibilities to solve this issue.

Comment: Sounds like a bad cell.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your battery is dead

Since it out of warranty you will need to buy a new one.

A search on your favorite search engine will probably yield many results

I searched for `Thinkpad Edge E430 replacement battery` and found results.